# Installing pdo_mysql on Amazon EC2 with PHP 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, amazon-ec2

I've created an Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.02 server and installed the following:

```
yum install php55 php55-mbstring php55-soap php55-gd php55-mcrypt php55-pdo httpd24
```

Apache and PHP work fine.  But I need pdo_mysql.so for a legacy version of Doctrine (1.x).  I cannot find out how to get pdo_mysql.so onto this system.  That file is not within the `/user/lib64/php/5.5/modules/` folder.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Install the package `php55-mysqlnd`. I believe this will provide mysql support to PDO.

Edit: 
For PHP 5.6 support, the package is `php56-mysqlnd`.

For PHP 7.0 support, the package is `php70-mysqlnd`.

For PHP 7.1 support, the package is `php71-mysqlnd`.

Comment: By Zeus' beard!  That did it!

Comment: Thanks, mate. Worked out OK.

Comment: When I try `yum install php55-mysqlnd` I get error `No package php55-mysqlnd available`

Comment: What can I do since 7.1 packages have been released yet?