# Amazon AMI PDO MYSQL driver missing. No package is available for PHP 7.1. How can I install the 7.1 PDO_MYSQL driver?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, centos

When attempting to run the database migrations, I get this error.

```
[PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513831/3742614), there is no available package yet. Is there any way I can get this installed? Running the following search confirms that there is no driver yet.

```
yum search php71w- | grep -i pdo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `php71w-mysql` or `php71w-mysqlnd` as listed under the [php71 package](https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/) on the Webtatic repository website. Here is a working Dockerfile to demonstrate:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM amazonlinux

RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
RUN yum install -y php71w-cli php71w-mysqlnd

$ docker run --rm $(docker build -q .) php -m | grep -i pdo
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

`yum install php-mysql` should do it.